# How to fix 'Row 1 was truncated; it contained more data than there were input columns' error when loading data from a csv file?

Tags: java, mysql

I am loading a csv file from a S3 bucket.  I'm not sure why I keep getting these warnings.  I have a lambda that runs the code every day but it will not successfully run the code with 64 warnings.

I've tried adding IGNORE in my sql statement. I checked the csv input columns at least 10 times when my load sql code.  I can't seem to find the issue.

My load script:

```
USE pauto;
LOAD DATA FROM S3 'csv file'
IGNORE INTO TABLE bmwloadsales
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' lines terminated by '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(@filetype,@dvdealerid, @vendordealerid, @dmstype, 
@dealnumber,@customernumber, @fullname, @salutation, @firstname, 
@middlename, @lastname,@suffix,@addressline1,@addressline2, 
@city, @state, @zip, @county, @homephone, @cellphone, @workphone, 
@workextension, @email1, @email2, @email3, @birthdate, 
@individualbusinessflag, @optout,@blockemail, 
@blockphone, @blockmail, @language, @customercreatedate, 
@customerlastactivitydate, @cobuyercustomernumber, @cobuyerfullname, 
@cobuyersalutation, @cobuyerfirstname, 
@cobuyermiddlename, @cobuyerlastname, @cobuyersuffix, 
@cobuyeraddressline1, @cobuyeraddressline2, @cobuyercity, @cobuyerstate, 
@cobuyerzip, @cobuyercounty,@cobuyerhomephone,
@cobuyercellphone, @cobuyerworkphone, @cobuyerworkextension, 
@cobuyeremail1, @cobuyeremail2, @cobuyeremail3, @cobuyerbirthdate, 
@cobuyerindividualbusinessflag, @cobuyeroptout, 
@cobuyerblockemail, @cobuyerblockphone, @cobuyerblockmail,@vin, @year, 
@make, @model, @modelnumber, @mileage, 
@description,@exteriorcolor,@newused,@stocknumber,@transmission,
```

@engineconfiguration, @trim, @enginenumber, @chassisnumber,@licenseplatenumber,

@deliverydate,@deliverymileage,@inventorydate,@inservicedate,@vinexplosionyear,@vinexplosionmake,
    @vinexplosionmodel,@vinexplosiontrim,@vinexplosiontransmissiontype,@vinexplosionfueltype,@vinexplosionenginesize,@vinexplosiongvwrange,@trade1vin,@trade1year,@trade1make,
    @trade1model,@trade1odometer,@trade1actualcashvalue,@trade1gross,@trade1payoff,@trade2vin,@trade2year,@trade2make,@trade2model,@trade2odometer,@trade2actualcashvalue,
    @trade2gross,@trade2payoff, @salesman1number,@salesman1name,@salesman2number,@salesman2name,@salesman3number,@salesman3name,@closingmanagernumber,@closingmanagername,
    @financemanagernumber,@financemanagername,@salesmanmanagernumber,@salesmanmanagername,@msrp,@listprice,@salesprice,@journalprice,@cost,@journalcost,@adjustments,
    @adjustedcost,@incentives,@packamount,@salenet,@totaltradeactualcashvalue,@totaltradegross,@weowefront,@totalfrontfeesaftermarketprofit,@totalfrontcommission,@totalfrontsales,
    @totalfrontcost,@frontgross,@financeprofit,@totalwarrantyprofit,@weoweback,@insuranceprofit,@totalbackfeesaftermarketprofit,@financereserve,@totalbackcommission,
    @totalbacksales,@totalbackcost,@backgross,@totalprofit,@grossprofit,@grosspayable,@dealstatus,@entrydate,@bookeddate,@finalizeddate,@contractdate,@accountingdate,
    @statuschangedate,@firstpaydate,@dealtype,@saletype,@bankid,@bankname,@bankaddress,@term,@amountfinanced,@apr,@monthlypayment,@paymenttotal,@rebates,@deposit,@downpayment,
    @totalnettrades,@totaldown,@balloonamount,@adjustedballoonamount,@holdbackamount,@totaldriveoffamount,@licensefee,@registrationfee,@documentationfee,@financecharge,
    @totalpickuppayments,@sellrate,@buyrate,@residualrate,@residualamount,@allowedmiles,@estimatedmiles,@mileagerate,@acquisitionfee,@basepayment,@securitydeposit,
    @totalcapitalreduction,@netcapitalcost,@leasedepreciationvalue,@dealerfees,@governmentfees,@totaltax,@registrationstate,@reportofsalenumber,@salesman1totalcommission,
    @salesman1frontcommission,@salesman1backcommission,@salesman2totalcommission,@salesman2frontcommission,@salesman2backcommission,@salesman3totalcommission,
    @salesman3frontcommission,@salesman3backcommission,@warranty1name,@warranty1sale,@warranty1cost,@warranty1miles,@warranty1term,@warranty2name,@warranty2sale,@warranty2cost,
    @warranty2miles,@warranty2term,@warranty3name,@warranty3sale,@warranty3cost,@warranty3miles,@warranty3term,@warranty4name,@warranty4sale,@warranty4cost,@warranty4miles,
    @warranty4term,@warranty5name,@warranty5sale,@warranty5cost,@warranty5miles,@warranty5term,@totalfeeaftermarketsale,@totalfeeaftermarketcost,@feeaftermarket1name,
    @feeaftermarket1sale,@feeaftermarket1cost,@feeaftermarket1profitindicator,@feeaftermarket2name,@feeaftermarket2sale,@feeaftermarket2cost,@feeaftermarket2profitindicator,
    @feeaftermarket3name,@feeaftermarket3sale,@feeaftermarket3cost,@feeaftermarket3profitindicator,@feeaftermarket4name,@feeaftermarket4sale,@feeaftermarket4cost,
    @feeaftermarket4profitindicator,@feeaftermarket5name,@feeaftermarket5sale,@feeaftermarket5cost,@feeaftermarket5profitindicator,@feeaftermarket6name,@feeaftermarket6sale)
    SET dealnumber=@dealnumber, 
    fullname=@fullname, 
    salutation=@salutation,
    firstname=@firstname,
    middlename=@middlename,
    lastname=@lastname,
    suffix=@suffix,
    address1=@addressline1,
    address2=@addressline2,
    city=@city,
    state=@state,
    zip=@zip,
    county=@county,
    homephone=@homephone,
    cellphone=@cellphone,
    email=@email1,
    indivorbus=@individualbusinessflag,
    cobuyerfullname=@cobuyerfullname,
    cobuyersalutation=@cobuyersalutation,
    cobuyerfirstname=@cobuyerfirstname,
    cobuyermiddlename=@cobuyermiddlename,
    cobuyerlastname=@cobuyerlastname,
    inventorydate=STR_TO_DATE(@inventorydate, "%m/%d/%Y"),
    vin=TRIM(@vin),
    year=STR_TO_DATE(@year,"%Y"),
    make=@make, 
    model=@model, 
    odometer=IFNULL(NULLIF(@mileage,''),0),
    dvddealerid=@dvdealerid,
    salesperson=@salesman1name,
    salesperson2=@salesman2name,
    purchasedhere='yes',
    carwashmember='',
    purchasedheredate=STR_TO_DATE(@contractdate, "%m/%d/%Y");

I would like the code to run without any warnings. Sorry I know its a long script....Thanks!

column header:

File Type   DV Dealer ID    Vendor Dealer ID    DMS Type    Deal Number Customer Number Full Name   Salutation  First Name  Middle Name Last Name   Suffix  Address Line 1  Address Line 2  City    State   Zip County  Home Phone  Cell Phone  Work Phone  Work Extension  Email 1 Email 2 Email 3 Birth Date  Individual/Business Flag    Opt Out Block Email Block Phone Block Mail  Language    Customer Create Date    Customer Last Activity Date Co-Buyer Customer Number    Co-Buyer Full Name  Co-Buyer Salutation Co-Buyer First Name Co-Buyer Middle Name    Co-Buyer Last Name  Co-Buyer Suffix Co-Buyer Address Line 1 Co-Buyer Address Line 2 Co-Buyer City   Co-Buyer State  Co-Buyer Zip    Co-Buyer County Co-Buyer Home Phone Co-Buyer Cell Phone Co-Buyer Work Phone Co-Buyer Work Extension Co-Buyer Email 1    Co-Buyer Email 2    Co-Buyer Email 3    Co-Buyer Birth Date Co-Buyer Individual/Business Flag   Co-Buyer Opt Out    Co Buyer Block Email    Co Buyer Block Phone    Co Buyer Block Mail VIN Year    Make    Model   Model Number    Mileage Description Exterior Color  New/Used    Stock Number    Transmission    Engine Configuration    Trim    Engine Number   Chassis Number  License Plate Number    Delivery Date   Delivery Mileage    Inventory Date  In Service Date VIN Explosion Year  VIN Explosion Make  VIN Explosion Model VIN Explosion Trim  VIN Explosion Transmission Type VIN Explosion Fuel Type VIN Explosion Engine Size   VIN Explosion GVW Range Trade 1 VIN Trade 1 Year    Trade 1 Make    Trade 1 Model   Trade 1 Odometer    Trade 1 Actual Cash Value   Trade 1 Gross   Trade 1 Payoff  Trade 2 VIN Trade 2 Year    Trade 2 Make    Trade 2 Model   Trade 2 Odometer    Trade 2 Actual Cash Value   Trade 2 Gross   Trade 2 Payoff  Salesman 1 Number   Salesman 1 Name Salesman 2 Number   Salesman 2 Name Salesman 3 Number   Salesman 3 Name Closing Manager Number  Closing Manager Name    Finance Manager Number  Finance Manager Name    Salesman Manager Number Salesman Manager Name   MSRP    List Price  Sales Price Journal Price   Cost    Journal Cost    Adjustments Adjusted Cost   Incentives  Pack Amount Sale Net    Total Trade Actual Cash Value   Total Trade Gross   We Owe Front    Total Front Fees/Aftermarket Profit Total Front Commission  Total Front Sales   Total Front Cost    Front Gross Finance Profit  Total Warranty Profit   We Owe Back Insurance Profit    Total Back Fees/Aftermarket Profit  Finance Reserve Total Back Commission   Total Back Sales    Total Back Cost Back Gross  Total Profit    Gross Profit    Gross Payable   Deal Status Entry Date  Booked Date Finalized Date  Contract Date   Accounting Date Status Change Date  First Pay Date  Deal Type   Sale Type   Bank ID Bank Name   Bank Address    Term    Amount Financed APR Monthly Payment Payment Total   Rebates Deposit Down Payment    Total Net Trades    Total Down  Balloon Amount  Adjusted Balloon Amount Holdback Amount Total Drive Off Amount  License Fee Registration Fee    Documentation Fee   Finance Charge  Total Pickup Payments   Sell Rate   Buy Rate    Residual Rate   Residual Amount Allowed Miles   Estimated Miles Mileage Rate    Acquisition Fee Base Payment    Security Deposit    Total Capital Reduction Net Capital Cost    Lease Depreciation Value    Dealer Fees Government Fees Total Tax   Registration State  Report of Sale Number   Salesman 1 Total Commission Salesman 1 Front Commission Salesman 1 Back Commission  Salesman 2 Total Commission Salesman 2 Front Commission Salesman 2 Back Commission  Salesman 3 Total Commission Salesman 3 Front Commission Salesman 3 Back Commission  Warranty 1 Name Warranty 1 Sale Warranty 1 Cost Warranty 1 Miles    Warranty 1 Term Warranty 2 Name Warranty 2 Sale Warranty 2 Cost Warranty 2 Miles    Warranty 2 Term Warranty 3 Name Warranty 3 Sale Warranty 3 Cost Warranty 3 Miles    Warranty 3 Term Warranty 4 Name Warranty 4 Sale Warranty 4 Cost Warranty 4 Miles    Warranty 4 Term Warranty 5 Name Warranty 5 Sale Warranty 5 Cost Warranty 5 Miles    Warranty 5 Term Total Fee/Aftermarket Sale  Total Fee/Aftermarket Cost  Fee/Aftermarket 1 Name  Fee/Aftermarket 1 Sale  Fee/Aftermarket 1 Cost  Fee/Aftermarket 1 Profit Indicator  Fee/Aftermarket 2 Name  Fee/Aftermarket 2 Sale  Fee/Aftermarket 2 Cost  Fee/Aftermarket 2 Profit Indicator  Fee/Aftermarket 3 Name  Fee/Aftermarket 3 Sale  Fee/Aftermarket 3 Cost  Fee/Aftermarket 3 Profit Indicator  Fee/Aftermarket 4 Name  Fee/Aftermarket 4 Sale  Fee/Aftermarket 4 Cost  Fee/Aftermarket 4 Profit Indicator  Fee/Aftermarket 5 Name  Fee/Aftermarket 5 Sale  Fee/Aftermarket 5 Cost  Fee/Aftermarket 5 Profit Indicator  Fee/Aftermarket 6 Name  Fee/Aftermarket 6 Sale

Comment: It would appear that table `bmwloadsales` has fewer columns than the number of values you have specified.

Comment: Yes that's what the error says but its not true....

Comment: Hey! you might want to format that code of yours. Also paste a (formatted) example of your CSV file header.

Comment: The sql code is from mysqlbench....I'm trying to get it to work properly then transfer it over to my lambda code. Thanks!

Comment: Why aren't there any commas in the header?

Comment: Its an csv file saved in S3 bucket...it looks like an excel file.